# "Jetzt" als Bezug auf die Vergangenheit?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-particle

In [diesem Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PLEZXIxspo), das die Schnitzelzubereitung betrifft, sagt der Typ bei 4:25:

> Wir haben ja hier die Schnitzel, die haben wir jetzt einfach im
> Supermarkt so gekauft.

Was bedeutet "jetzt" in diesem Satz? Ich verstehe (glaube ich) die normale zeitliche Bedeutung von "jetzt", aber hier bedeutet anscheinend das Wort etwas anderes, oder? Er kauft ja nichts, während er spricht, sondern in der Vergangenheit hat er etwas gekauft. Ist "jetzt" daher so ein Bezug auf die Vergangenheit?

Der Untertitel ist unklar (und ich vertraue Untertiteln sowieso nicht unbedingt). Er übersetzt "jetzt einfach" als "just", man weiß aber nicht, ob dieses englische "just" im Sinn von "gerade" oder "einfach" gemeint wird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ich würde das "jetzt" in diesem Beispiel nicht als [Adverb der Zeit](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jetzt_nun_heute_inzwischen) verstehen, sondern als [Partikel](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jetzt_nun_denn), wie zum Beispiel auch in

> Wo habe ich denn jetzt wieder meine Brille hingetan?

In [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/jetzt) wird diese Verwendung als "intensivierend, satzbelebend" bezeichnet. So sehe ich das in Deinem Beispiel auch, das "jetzt" verstärkt das folgende "einfach".

Übrigens, "jetzt" kann sich auch in der zeitlichen Bedeutung auf die Vergangenheit beziehen, nämlich wenn die erzählte Zeit in der Vergangenheit liegt:

> Sie atmete auf, als der Wachmann einfach vorüber ging. Jetzt war ihre Chance gekommen!

Comment: Gegen diese Deutung spricht, dass sowohl Duden als auch DWDS nur die Nutzung in Fragen vorsehen, und der Partikel nach Duden betont ist. Ich würde "jetzt" hier aber nicht betont lesen. Intensivierend ist "jetzt" hier nicht wirklich, er abschwächend.

Answer (score 3):

### Warum *jetzt* in einem Satz mit Perfekt Sinn macht

Da das Perfekt ausdrückt, dass eine Handlung abgeschlossen ist,
gibt es beim Perfekt immer zwei Zeitpunkte: Den der Handlung, und den, in dem sie abgeschlossen ist.

Welcher Zeitpunkt gemeint ist, ist klar, denn die Handlung ist in der Vergangenheit und der Zeitraum, an dem die Handlung abgeschlossen ist, ist in der Gegenwart.

"Jetzt" ist Gegenwart, in einem Satz mit Perfekt meint es also, dass die Handlung "jetzt" abgeschlossen ist.

Da Perfekt ohnehin ausdrückt, dass die Handlung jetzt abgeschlossen ist,
trägt das zusätzliche "jetzt" nicht viel zur Bedeutung bei.
Ein solches "jetzt" kann zwar viele Bedeutungen haben, aber der konkrete Satz steht im Rahmen einer Video-Anleitung, und in diesen sagt man nun einmal gerne "jetzt", um den nächsten Schritt anzukündigen. Die Deutung "in diesem Fall", wie von [user3519960](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71190/42116), ist auch plausibel.

Comment: Ein "jetzt" mit Perfekt kann meiner Meinung nach ausdrücken, dass die Handlung sehr kürzlich abgeschlossen wurde. Häufiger und klarer wäre da allerdings "gerade", und im Kontext vom Video ist diese Deutung auch hier nicht plausibel.

Answer (score 2):

"Jetzt" in diesem Zusammenhang würde ich als sehr umgangssprachlich bezeichnen, denn offensichtlich wird zu jenem Zeitpunkt nichts eingekauft.

In dieser Wendung hat das "Jetzt" eher die Bedeutung von "in diesem Fall" oder "bezogen auf unsere aktuelle Situation".

In diesem Sinn sind die Untertitel gar nicht so falsch.

Answer (score 0):

**Ja, "jetzt" mit Bezug auf die Vergangenheit!**

Es ist hilfreich anzunehmen, was schon Grimm bemerkte, dass *ja* und *je* sowie et-liches mehr im Gebrauch kaum auseinander zu halten sind. Da ist einerseits der Vergleich mit Latein *ius* zu *just*, Altenglisch *ae* zu *ever* usw. Schon deshalb ist nachvollziehbar, dass *just* seit Alters her eine gängige Entsprechung ist.

Andererseits steht dem ein Vergleich mit Latein *ipse*, *iam*, usw., Englisch *yon, yonder* und zudem spätes Mittelhochdeutsch *jetzund* und so fort (vereinzelt "wj ich dir jetzun hab erklert" https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/jetzund) in nichts nach.

Siehe für Latein weiteres bei Wikipedia, auszugsweise:

> *Iam* means, generally, “at some point previous” or “since some point previous”. In English, *already*, the most common translation, is used only to emphasize that this point might have been expected to be later, whereas *now* is used to emphasize that the statement was once false, even when the statement refers to a point in the past or future. *Iam* is used to express either.
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iam#Usage_notes

Siehe ebenso für das Urgermanische rekonstruiert [*ju](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/ju) "already; yet; now", daraus abgeleitet **juta* (*t wird regelmäßig zu /ts/, vgl. *Herz*, En. *heart*, doch nicht immer, vgl. *Fuß*, En. *foot*).

Die weitläufig akzeptierte Deutung "je zu" ([DWDS](https://dwds.de/wb/jetzt), [wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jetzt), *Duden*) ist dementsprechend abzulehnen, was die Schreibung der rigiden, redigierten hochdeutschen Kanzleisprache zwecks der Vereinheitlichung jedoch verbirgt, welche wiederum gehörigen Einflus auf die Aussprache geschulter Leser nimmt.

Die bisherigen Antworten lassen demnach die vielfältig möglichen Deutungen erahnen, die wohl fundiert, jedoch wenig attraktiv sind, denn dem Schnitzel kann es allenfalls egal sein; außgenommen es ging um den Frischegrad des Produktes. Dies scheint eher unwahrscheinlich.

Answer (score 0):

> Wir haben **ja** hier die Schnitzel, die haben wir **jetzt** einfach im Supermarkt **so** gekauft.

Die fett hervorgehobenen Wörter

- ja
- jetzt
- so

in diesem Satz sind lauter [Modalpartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel). Das sind Wörter, die die Proposition des Satzes nicht verändern. (Die Proposition ist die logische Aussage eines Satzes, ale etwas, das wahr oder falsch sein kann.) Mit anderen Worten: Die An- oder Abwesenheit von Modalpartikeln verändert nicht die eigentliche Aussage des Satzes. Zwar verändern auch Artikel, Bindewörter usw. ebenfalls nicht die Proposition, allerdings erfüllen diese Wörter eine grammatische Funktion, was auch Modalpartikel nicht zutrifft. Das heißt: Man kann alle Modalpartikel immer weglassen und hat am Ende noch immer einen grammatisch völlig korrekten Satz, der aus dasselbe Aussage wie der ursprüngliche Satz mit Modalpartikeln.

> Wir haben hier die Schnitzel, die haben wir einfach im Supermarkt gekauft.

Modalpartikel verändern aber die Emotion, die vom Satz transportiert wird.

Hier in German Stackexchange gibt es bereits mehr als 30 [Fragen und Antworten über Modalpartikel in deutscher Sprache](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Modalpartikel) und mehr als 120 [in englischer Sprache](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Modal%20particle). Daher bitte ich, sich dort weiter über dieses Thema zu informieren.

<sub>(Man könnte auch darüber diskutieren, ob auch das Wort *»einfach«* im vorliegenden Beispiel als Modalpartikel zu interpretieren sei, aber hier liegt es näher, davon auszugehen, dass ein adverbial verwendetes Adjektiv ist.)</sub>

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung und Links. Ich denke, dass der Gebrauch der Modalpartikel zu den größten und interessantesten Herausforderungen der deutschen Sprache gehört. Ich habe ähnliche Definitionen von "Modalpartikel" gelesen, aber sie sind für mich ein bisschen suspekt, weil Modalpartikel anscheinend manchmal zusätzliche Informationen hinzufügen. Wenn ich recht verstehe, bedeutet das obere "ja" "wie wir schon wissen" o.Ä. (glaube ich - ich kann hier natürlich falsch liegen), was noch Information enhält. Ich bin mir also nicht sicher, warum diese Information kein Teil der Proposition wäre.

Answer (score 0):

For me, *jetzt* in the given sentence means *dieses Mal* = *ausnahmsweise mal*, wherereas normally I would buy them at the butcher's. It's a colloquial way of replacing the standard temporal adverb *diesmal*.

*Einfach*, indeed, can be a particle, meaning '*to make short work*', '*quickly and easily*', which is quite close to the original meaning of *einfach* = '*to simplify matters*':

- Diskutier hier nicht lange herum, tu's einfach.
- Er war einfach abgereist, ohne irgendwem Bescheid zu sagen
- Es ist einfach nicht zu fassen, wie viele Fehler sie beim Schreiben noch macht.

*Jetzt* as well, can be used particle-like:

- Das bleibt jetzt aber unter uns!
- Das ist jetzt vielleicht nicht das optimale Beispiel, aber...
- Jetzt hab ich doch tatsächlich mein Bahnticket zu Hause liegen lassen!
- Das kann dir doch jetzt auch egal sein.
- Wie jetzt!? Die Hochzeit ist abgesagt?